# Can I do anything about "repaints on scroll" warning in Chrome for "overflow:scroll" div

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome DevTools, under Rendering, there's an option to "Show potential scroll bottlenecks".

When I enabled this, some `div` elements I have on the screen with `overflow:scroll` show a flag at the top saying "repaints on scroll."

I can't find a lot of documentation on this feature, and I don't know whether it's something I can actually fix or improve upon, or just a statement of fact - the divs have content, and they do indeed scroll.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can apply this CSS on the `div` with `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: auto` that create scroll bottlenecks.

```
transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

That will force the browser to create a new layer to paint this element, and sometimes fix scroll bottlenecks (especially with Webkit).

Comment: Google now supports the unprefixed `translateZ`

Comment: I think `-webkit-backface-visibily: hidden` should work as well.

Comment: @Shikkediel that does work as well, however you've misspelled it, and ideally you should include all vendor prefixes: `-moz-backface-visibility: hidden; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; backface-visibility: hidden;`

Comment: Ah, you're right @Chris Barr. I usually spell check better. The `webkit` prefix could be a good one for older browser versions. For mozilla I think it might not be necessary, that browser seems to handle repaints differently - like with large blocks of `fixed` position for example. But I guess that depends on the exact case, which isn't really given here.

Comment: `transform: translateZ(0)` is the old way. `will-change: transform` is the new way, but doesn't have IE11/Edge support.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean when you say the browser will create a new layer to paint the elements? I'd like to understand why this works

Comment: Until all modern browsers can fix the issue with 'will-change', this should continue to be known as the correct answer

Comment: Does this work in chromium browser? I am facing issues with mouse wheel

Comment: But beware that when using the transform: translateZ(0); trick, child with position:fixed will fail to work.

Answer (score 35):

Although the accepted answer solves the problem, it is worth looking at the CSS [`will-change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) property. This is preferred over `transform: translateZ(0);` in recent times. Here is an that article explains the difference in detail - https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/

```css
.scroll-container {
  will-change: transform;
}
```

Comment: This should be the preferred answer because it's not a hack unlike the top one.

Comment: Strangely though, `will-change: scroll-position` seems to have no effect.

Comment: So should I use both to support older browsers?

Comment: this fix a strange performance issue on our pages that have a scroll area

Comment: You can not just replace `translateZ(0)` with `will-change: transform`, right? You have to use them together?

Comment: Use it with value `transform`, `scroll-position`, `left`, `top` or if `contents` change to solve performance issues.

Comment: @Kulio You must use `will-change:transform` together with `translateZ(0)` to force a composit layer, because *the will-change property has no direct effect on the element it is applied to—it is merely a rendering hint to the browser allowing it to set up optimizations for the changes that will occur to that element*.

Answer (score 29):

This amazingly took me multiple days to track down what was going on, and only because I saw the one side-comment at the end of a bug report at 
[Chromium bugtracker Issue 514303](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=514303). Here's what's going on and how to fix it:

There exists a concept called "LCD text", which I believe means subpixel antialiasing, i.e. "crisper sharper text". Unfortunately, this feature is mutually incompatible with compositor-accelerated scrolling.

LCD text is enabled by default (at least on Blink/Webkit?) on all platforms which are not high-DPI (most normal monitors; i.e. you can check `console.log(devicePixelRatio)`). On the other hand, LCD text is DISABLED by default on high-DPI devices (think Retina display, or most mobile devices and tablets) since you don't really need a "crisper sharper text" feature on high-DPI platforms.

Therefore the opposite is true for compositor-accelerated scrolling: it is only possible on high-DPI platform where LCD text is disabled.

However, you can force compositor-accelerated scrolling on most monitors by promoting the `overflow:scroll` element to its own layer, by either adding `will-change:transform` to that element, or any hackish equivalent which will force the overflow element to be the parent of its own layer (such as `transform:translateZ(0)`). (Do note that vendor prefixes are being removed.)

tl;dr: Chrome doesn't suppose both subpixel antialiasing AND gpu-assisted scrolling; pick one or the other. Subpixel antialiasing is the default pick on Chrome (except on cellphones and retina displays, because their text is so small you don't need the feature, so you won't notice this issue on those platforms). Override this by forcing the element into its own compositor Layer with `will-change:transform` (but note that maybe your text won't look crystal perfect).

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same "repaints on scroll" issue with an input of type text.  By removing the input's "placeholder" attribute, the warning disappeared.

Answer (score -6):

Nope, you cant modify that, it is a Chrome function to allow you to know, what's painted each update in the window.

Updates can be a lot of different things (scroll, mousemove, interval, requestanimationframe,...).

But, now you know that, you can enhance your code.

If (I dont know), the browser alway re-paint a `div` if it is set to overflow scroll you maybe can do some JS to set to `overflow hidden` when out of screen...

[This post](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/) talk about different Browser layout