# onscroll - browser rendering optimization - layers hack - will-change

Tags: html, css, browser, google-chrome-devtools

I've an application with a scrollable element that contains a list of items.

I'd like to optimize the rendering for jank free scrolling, with some tricks that are described in http://aerotwist.com/blog/on-translate3d-and-layer-creation-hacks/ for exemple

Just would like to know: where should I force the browser to create layers? Am I supposed to create a rendering layer around each of my list items?

I also would like to know why the browser isn't able to do this on his own, because when an element is scrollable, it makes sens to me that we will move the content of this element up and down without changing the rendering of the inner content right? So why doesn't the browser creates a layer for the inner content of any scrollable element?

By the way, is this layer creation hack consistent across browsers?

**Edit:**

I've noted that it is now possible to indicate to the browser that some changes will happen.
I could use for exemple: `will-change: scroll-position;` according to [this article](http://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/)

However, I still don't understand why the browser needs this, because if we set `overflow-y: auto;`
 or `overflow-y: scroll;`, it seems obvious that the scroll position is expected to change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I do anything about "repaints on scroll" warning in Chrome for "overflow:scroll" div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741502/can-i-do-anything-about-repaints-on-scroll-warning-in-chrome-for-overflowscr)

Answer (score -1):

If you are scrolling list of elements that are 'static' (they don't change their relative position, size, opacity etc. while you scroll) there isn't much that you can do to improve the scrolling performance. That's because your scrollable content *is* already promoted to a separate layer. You can easily test it yourself:

- open [this demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/7w8TC/1/show/light/) (it doesn't use `translate3d` nor `will-change`),
- enable 'Show composited layer borders' in the DevTools
- and observe the result.

[image: composited layer borders]

Orange border around the scrollable content indicates that it is on a separate layer.

If you are experiencing janky scrolling then try to narrow your issue down (e.g. using Timeline in the DevTools). `translateZ(0)` is not a silver bullet for all performance problems.

Comment: I'm not sure if Chrome's behaviour has changed, but statically positioned scrollable elements no longer seem to be promoted to their own layer.