# Side-Scrolling images rendering slowly

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll

In my React app:

I have a side scrolling slider of React components that contain images. The user can scroll to the left and right using the standard `overflow: scroll` CSS mechanism.

When the viewport is narrow and the user scrolls fast, the elements sliding into view are invisible for a noticeable amount of time before they render. I have tried to prevent the React side of things from re-rendering anything, and it seems that the components do not re-render. This has **not** solved the problem.

My code is somewhat like this:

CSS

```
.sliderContainer {
    overflow: hidden
}

.slider {
    display: flex;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

HTML rendered by the React component:

```
<div class="sliderContainer">
    <div class="slider">
    // this contains many (20+) components similar to this:
        <div class="contentComponent">
            <img class="contentImage" />
            <img class="authorImage" />
            <p>some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So my question is this:
**Does fast side-scrolling always cause the scrolling items to render slowly?** If not, what could cause this effect, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Can you add the code you are using? Will help with figuring out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution in this question: 
[Can I do anything about "repaints on scroll" warning in Chrome for "overflow:scroll" div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741502/can-i-do-anything-about-repaints-on-scroll-warning-in-chrome-for-overflowscr)

I needed to search for "repaint" rather than "re-render".

The solution to allow more fluid scrolling, is to give the .slider div the following css property:

```
transform: translateZ(0);
```