# How to improve scrolling speed of an Angular list?

Tags: javascript, angular, performance

I use Angular 10 and have a 2-column layout where both columns contain a `mat-list` item with thousands of elements. On scrolling the speed drops dramatically, so I addressed this issue as follows:

- Simplified the impact of CSS
- Added `transform: translateX(0) translateZ(0);` to the columns ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741502/can-i-do-anything-about-repaints-on-scroll-warning-in-chrome-for-overflowscr))
- Added [trackBy](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) support for the `ngFor` list
- Removed unnecessary calls from the HTML template
- Added a lazy display behaviour which only loads new elements once the user scrolls to the end of the list

Now I have two questions:

1. In both components (for each column) I added a `HostListener('mousewheel')` to achieve this 'lazy display behaviour' which looks like this:

```js
  @HostListener('mousewheel', ['$event'])
  scroll(event: MouseEvent) {
    clearTimeout(this.scrollTimeout);
    this.scrollTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.load_More_Elements_If_End_Of_List_Is_Reached();
    }, 250);
  }
```

It seems that this simple function also slows down the performance by several FPS. Does Javascript have a builtin event I can attach to the last element so I don't need to explicitly check this inside Javascript. Something like `(onDisplay)="load_more_elements()"`

2. Is there any other improvement I am missing?

Comment: Have a look at angular material SDK - virtualscroll directive. So specifically  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport> on https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview

Comment: @RyanWilson Isn't mat-list used for "lists"? It is not a business requirement, so I am free to update the views. Is mat-list really that 'slow'?

Comment: @MikeOne Thanks, I will look into this!

Comment: Thats what I meant, it is not any requirement. I am free to make any changes in this regard. As long as i have a list at the end :-)

Comment: @DanielStephens Then I suggest looking into using a filtered list, (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678206/angular-2-filter-search-list) For me, I would not want to have to scroll through thousands of options to find something I'm looking for.

Comment: Ok, bc I implemented this filter manually with mat-list

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package to build an infinite scroll: [link](https://github.com/orizens/ngx-infinite-scroll)
And you can follow this video for more details: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cy5MjeXZobE)

Basically, in your template:

```
<div
  class="search-results"
  infiniteScroll
  [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
  [infiniteScrollThrottle]="50"
  (scrolled)="onScroll()"
></div>
```

Whenever you scroll, `onScroll` is gonna get executed

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Unfortunately I don't need an infinite scroll, but that looks good nonetheless